# Cannot launch AVD & SDK manager (Android Studio 0.2.1)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

Having problems to launch AVD & SDK manager since the latest A/S update.

[image]

Comment: are you using Eclipse IDE or any other?

Comment: nop, just the new Android Studio

Comment: Do you have SDK Manager.exe in your android-sdk folder (outside of studio). It should run outside of studio. Can you run it outside of studio? Sometimes the updates don't copy over correctly during the installation (write protected directories). You can manually install the tools from a zip file from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and fixed it by giving Write and Modify permissions to the full android studio folder.

Answer (score 2):

Just need to set a environment variable 'JAVA_HOME' and make it point to the folder where Java is installed. If you are not quit familiar with environment variables, what you do is just these steps:

1. Right click on "My Computer", select "Properties"
2. Select "Advanced System Configuration"
3. Select "Advance" tab, and click the "Environment Variable" button.
4. In the user variables, create a new variable called "JAVA_HOME", and specify the path to where java is installed(in my case, I installed java in "E:\Developing Tools\Java"), click OK to save it.

After that, restart Intellij IDEA, and you should be able to open the AVD manager panel.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, try running Android Studio as an administrator.